# Why JComponents does not appear in the frame?

Tags: java

I'm pretty new to java. And i can't get this to work... I'm trying to add components using this code:

```
    public class Board
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
           JFrame window = new JFrame("Tellraw Generator");
           window.setVisible(true);
           window.setSize(400, 600);
           window.setResizable(false);
           window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
           JPanel panel = new JPanel();
           JLabel label = new JLabel();
           panel.setLayout(null);
           window.add(panel);
           //"Generate" Button
           JButton button1 = new JButton("Generate");
           button1.setBounds(262, 485, 100, 37);
           panel.add(button1);
           //"Add Text" Button
           JButton button2 = new JButton("Add Text");
           button2.setBounds(51, 337, 88, 33);
           panel.add(button2);
           //Title
           JLabel txt1 = new JLabel("Tellraw Generator");
           txt1.setFont(new Font("Minecrafter Alt Regular", Font.BOLD, 29));
           txt1.setBounds(61, 18, 278, 30);
           panel.add(txt1);
        }
    }
```

But when i'm trying to do it, the components aren't showing up on the screen.

So are there someone who can tell me why it isn't working/Showing up and how i can add it in ?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see code for JTextField here, might be you forgot adding that!

Comment: `JTextField` is not showing because there is no `textfield` declaration.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33302537/why-jcomponents-does-not-appear-in-the-frame/33302637#33302637

Answer (score 0):

You mean that `JLabel` and `JButton` don't appear? right ? not `JTextField` because there is no `JTextField` in the code

Anyway just add this line of code to the end:

```
window.add(panel);
```

Here you are adding the `JPanel` that contains all the `JComponent`s to the `JFrame`

Answer (score 0):

and always: have the `setVisible(true)` call as last call. Everything that you add to the window/frame must be done before the setVisible call

Answer (score 0):

This is how to declare a JTextField

> final JTextField variableName = new JTextField(size);

This is how you get the text from JTextField

> variableName.getText()

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Board
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
           JFrame window = new JFrame("Tellraw Generator");
           window.setVisible(true);
           window.setSize(400, 600);
           window.setResizable(false);
           window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
           JPanel panel = new JPanel();
           JLabel label = new JLabel();
           panel.setLayout(null);
           window.add(panel);
           //"Generate" Button
           JButton button1 = new JButton("Generate");
           button1.setBounds(262, 485, 100, 37);
           panel.add(button1);
           //"Add Text" Button
           JButton button2 = new JButton("Add Text");
           button2.setBounds(51, 337, 88, 33);
           panel.add(button2);
           //Title
           JTextField txt1 = new JTextField ();
           txt1.setFont(new Font("Minecrafter Alt Regular", Font.BOLD, 29));
           txt1.setBounds(61, 18, 278, 30);
           panel.add(txt1);
        }
    }
```